Flutter_quill background color
I'm using the flutter_quill library and I can't figure out how to change the background colour of the editor. I don't mean the background colour of the text, I mean the background colour of the editor itself.
By default it seems to be transparent because it is the colour of its parent widget.
Thanks

Yes its transparent

You can move the toolbar and editor inside Container, and set the color of container.
Example :
Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: QuillToolbar.simple(
              configurations: QuillSimpleToolbarConfigurations(
                controller: _controller,
                sharedConfigurations: const QuillSharedConfigurations(
                  locale: Locale('de'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 200,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            color: Colors.red,
            child: QuillEditor.basic(
              configurations: QuillEditorConfigurations(
                controller: _controller,
                readOnly: false,
                sharedConfigurations: const QuillSharedConfigurations(
                  locale: Locale('de'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )


